# Rails: Issues with getting Bootstrap Typeahead to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

On Rails, I've implemented Searchkick so that it's working properly, i.e. a user can search in my searchbox and be taken to movies#index with the proper search results:

View:

```
<%= form_tag movies_path, method: :get, :id=>"search" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: 'form-control', id: "movie_search" %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @movies = Movie.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
    else
      @movies = Movie.all.page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

But I can't seem to get the autocomplete to work. Here's my autocomplete action:

Route:

```
resources :movies, only: :index do
collection do
  get :autocomplete 
end
```

end

Controller:

```
 def autocomplete
    render json: Movie.search(params[:query], {
      fields: ["title^5", "description"],
      limit: 10,
      load: false,
      misspellings: {below: 5}
    }).map(&:title)
  end
```

JS:

```
 $("#movie_search").typeahead({
        name: "movie",
        remote: "/movies/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
      });
```

I've included twitter typeahead.js in my vendor assets and confirmed it's loading. I can visit the autocomplete endpoint and get json like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/movies/autocomplete?query=war
```

.

```
[
"War Dogs",
"War Machine",
"Hart's War",
"Dirty Wars",
"Sorority Wars",
"Bride Wars",
"War Story",
"A War",
"War Pigs",
"War Witch"
]
```

Still, autocomplete is not working in my search form field. Is there an obvious mistake? I'm seeing no errors in the dev console and search doesn't appear to be happening as I type (i.e. nothing happening in the back end console).

Comment: typeahead version?

Comment: just downloaded from the main typeahead page. v 0.11.1

Comment: From where did you take this remote example?

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#heres-how-to-make-it-work-with-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Bloodhound, the typeahead suggestion engine for your usecase. Try the following, modifying as per your requirement:

```js
var movies = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    url: '/movies/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
    transform: function(response) {
      return response;
    }
  }
});

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'movie',
  source: movies
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The current version of typeahead.js does not have the default wildcard parameter `%QUERY`anymore. You have to configure it explicitly if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `searchkick autocomplete: [:title]` in your model?

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick autocomplete: [:title]
  has_many: .....
end
```

Try to add `autocomplete: true` to your `autocomplete` too and you'll need to reindex after making the change.